# Training Models with 1 Hidden Layer

Tags: neural-network

for a multi-layer neural network is stochastic gradient descent(SGD) guaranteed to reach a global optimum?

Answer (score 1):

According to the paper *'Global Optimality in Neural Network Training'* [Haeffele, B.D. and Vidal, R., 2017] (https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Haeffele_Global_Optimality_in_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf) a global optimum for a neural network with 1 hidden layer is guaranteed but only under certain conditions. The layer must be big enough and the activation/regularization functions must be of a certain type. For example, ReLU activations satisfy the conditions but sigmoid activations do not.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the complexity of the data. If the data representation is enough for one hidden layer then yes, it is possible, or at least it'll be able to find the best solution possible.

If the dataset is highly dimensional then it's unlikely that the neural network reaches a good generalization of the problem. So a local optimum is probably the only conclusion that the network will be able to find.